# Does entropy of the system increase if two objects at different temperatures are touched?

Tags: entropy

Consider an object A and another B, the temperature of these objects is different.
These two objects form an isolated system. Now if we bring the two objects in contact, does the entropy of the system increase?
Do not consider radiation and other process by which entropy may increase, only answer based on how the change in average energies of the particles in A and B changes entropy.

Also entropy is the logarithm of number of states that a particle can occupy, dont answer using randomness or diorder factors.

Comment: *Also entropy is the number of states that a particle can occupy* You missed a logarithm there.

Comment: Added logarithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we ignore black body radiation which will bring the two bodies into thermal equilibrium in an isolated system, even if not touching, it all depends on the [thermal conductivity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity)

> In physics, thermal conductivity (often denoted k, λ, or κ) is the property of a material to conduct heat. It is evaluated primarily in terms of Fourier's Law for heat conduction.
>
> Heat transfer occurs at a lower rate across materials of low thermal conductivity than across materials of high thermal conductivity

There will be heat transfer dependent on the thermal conductivity and the surface of contact. This increases the entropy

> [the entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) of the system is the natural logarithm of that number of configurations, multiplied by the Boltzmann constant kB

as the number of configurations increases by the transfer of heat, i.e. kinetic/vibrational energy transfer at the molecular level introduces a large number of new  microstates in the system.

Comment: But the microstates are increased for the object which rises in temperature the other object would lose some microstates so would still net sum be positive or zero?

Comment: Each extra microstate increases the closed two body system entropy. Before contact,N microstates, one contact point N+1 microstates.

Comment: But if we seperate them after contact then what?

Comment: @Rishabh the interactions induced by the process of separation will increase the microstates.